# SQLAlchemy self-referencing model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm building a model that stores emails with a set of properties:

```
email_list_table = Table('email_list', Base.metadata,
                         Column('email_id', String, ForeignKey('emails.id')),
                         Column('list_id', Integer, ForeignKey('lists.id'))
                        )

class Email(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'emails'

  id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
  from_email = Column(String, nullable=False)
  from_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
  date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
  in_reply_to = Column(String)
  subject = Column(String, nullable=False)
  content = Column(String, nullable=False)
  lists = relationship("List", secondary=email_list_table)
  references = relationship("Email") # This is the issue 

  def __repr__(self):
    return "<Email(id='%s', from='%s', subject='%s')>" % (self.id, self.from_name, self.subject)

class List(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'lists'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String, nullable=False)
  email = Column(String, nullable=False)
  description = Column(String, nullable=False)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "<List(id='%s')>" % (self.id)
```

I would like to represent the `references` relationship as a list of emails. For example, an email can reference more than one other email and be referenced by more than one email.

In traditional SQL, I would use a second table with a composite primary key of a `referrer_id` and `referenced_id` and when querying I would join the two tables to get my list of referenced emails. This would make it simple to find what emails are referenced by a given ID and what emails a given ID references.

I looked at the docs on SQLAlchemy for [Adjacency List Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/self_referential.html) but I'm not sure the example there applies to my model (I guess I could add a column for `referrer_id`, but that wouldn't produce the same table structure as I expect, with the 'join' table).

What's the best/most correct way to produce the model I expect with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the answer I wanted by creating a second table and referencing it in the `Email` class like this:

```
email_references = Table('email_references', Base.metadata,
                         Column('referencer_id', String, ForeignKey('emails.id'), primary_key=True),
                         Column('referenced_id', String, ForeignKey('emails.id'), primary_key=True)
                    )

class Email(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'emails'

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    from_email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    from_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    in_reply_to = Column(String)
    subject = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    lists = relationship("List", secondary=email_list_table)
    references = relationship("Email",
                              secondary=email_references,                              
                        primaryjoin=id==email_references.c.referencer_id,
                          secondaryjoin=id==email_references.c.referenced_id
                         )
```